# MVC 4 Jquery $.post issue, Post not working :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In the following my initData is Countries name with ID #s.

What I want to do is on changing the country, get the City names list which I have implemented in a class and it works. However on drop down change I don't know how to post back and get those cities :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
    <select class="Countries"></select>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var initData= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))

        $(function() {
            var $select = $('.Countries');
            $(".Countries").append("<option value='0'>--Select Country--</option>");
            $.each(initialData, function(i, country) {
                var option = $('<option>', {
                    value: country.CountryID
                }).html(country.CountryName).appendTo($select);

            });
        });

        $('.Countries').change(function() {
             var postData = [];
                alert(postData);
                postData.push({value: $(this).val()});
                $.post('@Url.Action("Cities")', postData, function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert('Retrieve list of cities');
                    }

                }, 'json');

        });
    });
    </script>
```

My controller:

```
     public ActionResult Cities(int id)
    {
        List<CityModel> listCity = _da.GetCities(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Have you debug your code? Does you $.post() fires? Does it reach Cities()? Does Cities() returns Json?

Comment: No it does not get that far. Doesn't go beyond postData.push.

Comment: postData

ReferenceError: postData is not defined

Comment: So, alert works but not push? are you sure? Are you receiving an empty popup?

Comment: I  json jquerified and I have [{"value":"24"},{"value":"24"} wich is the ID I need to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ID was undefined meaning there was not related name for it. and postdata only contained Value ..  .. after adding ID it worked.

```
  postData.push({name: 'id', value: $(this).val()});
```